# Dell Latitude E6520 overheating

Tags: 11.10, overheating

I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu 11.10. My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6520, Sandy Bridge platform. The system cooling fan is crazy all the time. I don't do any intensive tasks. I really hope my laptop doesn't become a mushroom cloud.

1. I suppose there's no perfect way to solve this... Can I lower the CPU frequency?
2. Jupiter 0.0.51 was installed (power save mode).
3. Cooling worked in my Windows 7 system until I deleted it. (I won't go back to Windows 7.)

Comment: You could try applying some of these: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_i915_power

Comment: Same problem here. Best thing for us is to wait for the Kernel update for 11.10 which I hope will take care of the overheating problems on notebooks once and for all

Comment: I also have a Dell Latitude E6520 but I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed though that it happens when i plug in any devices (mouse, keyboard) into usb 3.0.

So i'm using 1 usb 2.0 slot now with a usb hub. It doesn't solve the problem completely but system stays at a low fan rate for a longer time.

You can lower CPU frequency, but in my case (DELL INSPIRON N7110 i7 on Linux 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) CPU was pretty cool and still the same horrible fan noise.

In case you'd like to experiment with CPU frequency you can try this script

```
#!/bin/bash
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 0
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 1
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 2
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 3
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 4
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 5
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 6
cpufreq-set -g powersave -c 7
```

You would need `cpufreq` installed for this to work.

```
sudo apt-get install cpufreq
```

Also try cpufreq-info to see the state.

Comment: As far as I know the Latitude E6520 does not have USB 3.0 (at least mine doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

You can help test the power fix by trying new kernels on your machine and logging the results, see this wiki page:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement

Answer (score 0):

I suggest buying a USB fan from like Wal-Mart or something. They do wonders and they're only $20 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that overheating happens mostly, when laptop (Dell N7110) is ON and its battery is charging.
Therefore, i try to charge the battery when laptop is OFF and when i switch it on it doesn't overheat because of the charging.

Btw, even if i charge my laptop when it's ON overheating stops in a few minutes after battery gets fully charged.

Please, also check if it happens when you use USB devices. In my case it used to get terribly overheated with usb 3.0 ports, and not so much with usb 2.0 port.
And just recently i've discovered that it doesn't overheat when i use esata port instead for usb devices - so it almost completely solved my issue.
I've also set a limit for maximum CPU rate to be 1600Mhz

$cpuspeed_gurdian.sh 800M 1600M

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 0
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 0
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 1
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 1
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 2
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 2
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 3
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 3
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 4
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 4
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 5
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 5
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 6
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 6
cpufreq-set -g conservative -c 7
cpufreq-set -d $1 -u $2 -c 7
```